# Tab 'a' click issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a simple tab script with scroll plugin, When I click on each tab, the scroll of that tab will be activated, but there is a problem because if you click two times on each tab you will have two instance of scroll on your page! here is my code, Any ideas?

**P.S I using mCustomScrollbar plugin.**

```
(function($){
    $(window).load(function(){
                $('ul.tabs').each(function(){
                var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');
                $active = $($links.filter('[href="' + location.hash + '"]')[0] || $links[0]);
                $active.addClass('active');
                $content = $($active.attr('href'));
                $links.not($active).each(function() {
                    $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
                });
                // Set scrollbar to main item
                $('#mContent').mCustomScrollbar();
                // Bind the click event handler
                $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e)
                {
                    var $currentScroll = null, $currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
                    switch ($currentTab)
                    {
                        case '#tabs-contentDescription':
                              $currentScroll = '#mContent';
                              break;
                        case '#tabs-contentChangelog':
                              $currentScroll = '#mChangelog';
                              break;
                        case '#tabs-contentPermission':
                              $currentScroll = '#mPermission';
                              break;
                    }
                    console.log('Current tab is: ' + $currentTab + ' And current scroll div is :' + $currentScroll);
                    // Make the old tab inactive.
                    $active.removeClass('active');
                    $content.hide();
                    // Update the variables with the new link and content
                    $active = $(this);
                    $content = $($(this).attr('href'));
                    // Make the tab active.
                    $active.addClass('active');
                    $content.show();
                    $($currentScroll).mCustomScrollbar();
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
        });
    });
}) (jQuery);
```

Comment: Why not check to see if the tab that was clicked is already active? i.e. hasClass('active'). If it is, then don't add the scroll.

Comment: Also, you always call `.mCustomScrollbar()` but never destruct or destroy previous instances.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp How can i destroy my previous instances ?

Comment: Not sure, it depends on the implementation of `mCustomScrollbar`. If it adds continuous activity to you page, it should have a destruct/destroy method that you can call, so it stops the "old" instance before you start another.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp Yes, there is a method that called 'delete' but I have a problem to detect old instance for destruction, how can I detect old instance ?!

Comment: You can use, for e.g., a global variable to hold the 'active' element. Then BEFORE update that variable, call delete() on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A smiplified example of what I'm suggesting above in the comments:

```
var active;

(function($){
    $(window).load(function(){

    [...]

    if(active) $(active).delete();
    active = $active = $(this);

    [...]

)}) (jQuery);
```